# Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lokio/AsyncTimeout;

Tags: .net, xamarin, java-8, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin and When I try to build my solution I see the below error:

> Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lokio/AsyncTimeout;
>   7>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lokio/AsyncTimeout$1;
>   7>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lokio/AsyncTimeout$2;
>   7>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lokio/AsyncTimeout$Watchdog;
>   7>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lokio/Base64;
>   7>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lokio/Buffer;
>   7>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lokio/Buffer$1;
>   7>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lokio/Buffer$2;
>   7>  Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lokio/BufferedSink;

Can someone explain this error and steps to solve this?

Comment: @SushiHangover - Exactly to say code is not causing this error. I believe it is something related to packages.

Comment: In diagnostic logging mode, what is the exact msbuild task/exception/stacktrace  that is reported? i.e. is it a desugar error, etc..?

Comment: How do I see that log? I mean path

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting#diagnostic-msbuild-output

Comment: @SushiHangover - pasted a log in this link https://pastebin.com/3h8SBAHF

Comment: This typically happens due to a mismatch of versions of the library or you have a NuGet package adding a duplicate dependency which adds the respective classes to the dex list again and throws this error.